# Why didn't WhatsApp deploy end-to-end encrypted backups to me?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, google-drive

It looks like the e2e encrypted backups are rolled out in production since a while. You can essentially encrypt Google Drive backups with a key that is unknown to WhatsApp/Meta Inc.

I found that once she changed phone, my mum had this option. I still don't have it. I never enabled Google Drive backups. I tried to authorize Google Drive, hoping that WA will display me the option to encrypt backups.

Nothing happens.

I also tried to reset WA data and restoring a backup, but I can't still encrypt my backups.

I'd really like to use e2e encrypted backups.

My WA folder weighs more than 3GB over the last 10 years.

Is there a reason why WhatsApp doesn't offer, despite keeping the app up to date, e2e encrytped backups to all users? What can I do to enable such feature?

Comment: Did you do these steps? From the question it looks like you didn't. https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/chats/how-to-turn-on-and-turn-off-end-to-end-encrypted-backup/?lang=en

Comment: There is no option for encrypted backups, that's why I said 'deploy'

Comment: [Yet to be rolled though announced in October](https://www.google.com/search?q=whatsapp+end+to+end+encrypted+backup+option+not+available&source=lnt&tbs=qdr:y&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIsZG-4Jz0AhXvxjgGHXH2DaQQpwV6BAgBECU&biw=1366&bih=609&dpr=1)

Comment: Which version is your whatsapp messager? Mine is 2.21.22.26 and it has it.